# How to add controls to ReportViewer?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I want to create report with my own controls, But the controls don't appear in the report!

I tried this:

```
GridView1.DataSource=(Order.GetDailyReport());
   GridView1.DataBind();
   ReportViewer1.Controls.Add(GridView1);
```

But nothing appeared!

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation

## [Customize the Report Viewer Web Part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326214.aspx)

But why would you want to add a gridView anyway? it is more meant for controls like the buttons you see on the toolbar.

I think you are trying to build it dynamically because the reportviewer comes with its own table.

You just need to change the way you populate the datasource:

Here is an example of how you would achieve that:

```
DataTable dt = Order.GetDailyReport();
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));
```

No need for gridview